# How to compare character with ) or( in control statements?

Tags: c

i'm trying to write following function, it will return 1 if `prcd` of `op1>op2` (and we assume `+-*/()` are only characters)

```
int prcd(char op1,char op2)
{
    switch(op1)
    {
        case '(':
            return 0;
            break;
        case ')':
            if(op2=='(') //doesn't work
            return 

        case '*':
        case '/':
        return 1;
        break;

        case '+':
        case '-':
            if(op2=='*' ||op2=='/')
            return 0;
            else return 1;
        break;

        default:
            return printf("invalid");
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens when you call your function? *How* do you call it? With what arguments? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: There's a missing semicolon after the return in the line below the comment, but that's not the issue, is it

Comment: Just as a point of style, you don't need any `break` or `else` after a `return` statement, since it will not be executed. Although your `case ')':` can fall through to the next case, since the `return` is conditional, and the case lacks any `break;` ;-)

Comment: Since all the cases `return` you could omit the `default` case and move `return printf("invalid");` to the end of the function. My compiler warns me that the function does not return any value. Better still, restructure the code. Anyway `printf` returns the number of characters printed, so the function will not return any useful value (7) in the default case.

Answer (score 0):

```
case ')':
{
    if(op2=='(') //doesn't work
        return 
}
```

Besides missing the ;, you are returning without the value (which is an int).

Upon successful return, printf function return the number of characters printed. Are you sure this is what you want? It appears that you are using the return value from printf (7) as an error retur. Wouldn't something like -1 be better?

I put in the brackets for each case because it makes it easier to read and see how it is set up. I also put the break in the default even though it is not needed because I want to keep the habit with every case.

You would be better off using.

```
int prcd(char op1,char op2)
{
    int retval;
    switch(op1)
    {
        case '(':
        {
            retval = 0;
            break;
        }
        case ')':
        {
            if(op2=='(')
            retval = 1;
            break; 
        }
        case '*':
        case '/':
        {
            retval = 1;
            break;
        }
        case '+':
        case '-':
        {
            if(op2=='*' ||op2=='/') retval 0;
            else retval 1;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            retval = printf("invalid"); // value is 7
            // would retval = -1; be a better error return?
            break;
        }
    }
    return retval;  
}
```

Comment: What would you say about the usefulness of the return value from `printf` in the default case?

Comment: He might use it as a test for an error since it is so much larger than the other values. I should expand that sentence. I left it in because he used it as the return value. He could also have returned -1 or something else.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to use case you have to use {statment} , and you put inside the code you need to apply , another thing is you have used return but you did not say what to return .